# Which algorithms have runtime recurrences like $T(n) = \sqrt{n}\,T(\sqrt{n}) + O(n)$?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, reference-request, runtime-analysis, recurrence-relation

The algorithms using the ["divide and conquer" (wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithms) design strategy often have the time complexity of the form $T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n)$, where $n$ is the problem size. Classic examples are binary search ($T(n) = T(n/2) + O(1)$) and merge sort ($T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O(n)$).

> Do you know any algorithms (probably using "divide and conquer") that have the time complexity of the form $T(n) = \sqrt{n} \cdot T(\sqrt{n}) + O(n)$?

Comment: A good way to find such algorithms may be to look into [papers citing the article by Akra & Bazzi](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=16306462122499300052&as_sdt=5,39&sciodt=0,39&hl=en) which [provides a tool for solving such recurrences asymptotically](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/10373/98).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of an algorithm, which do something linear with an integer list of length $n$, for example computes the maximum. Afterwards, the algorithm divides the list of length $n$ into $\sqrt{n}$ lists of length $\sqrt{n}$ and starts the algorithm for them. The result of the algorithm is for example the product of the computed maximum and the results of the $\sqrt{n}$ lists. For the base case, a list of length $1$, you can return  the value of the only element.

This algorithm has the time complexity, you asked for.

Comment: To give a concrete example, Mergesort could be implemented in this way. In massively parallel settings, this may even make sense.